# Referencing two database projects (same database) containing the same objects will unexpectedly build

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I have a Comp1 project that has a schema definition ("tmp") and a table definition:

[image]

Then I create a Main project that has the same definition of [tmp].[table1]. If I create a "same database" reference from the Main project to the Comp1, I get the expected error of "The model already has an element that has the same name...":

[image]

Now, if I create a new Comp2 project and a Schema "one" and create the "same database" relations as following, I expected the same error for the table table1 and the schema "tmp" in the Main project. But I get a successful building:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey Luca, Do you want to put your project on GitHub or something and I'll test with my version?

Comment: Hi Ed, you can find the solution here: http://1drv.ms/1Tiqj0A

Comment: I would raise a connect item, it will probably be a "won't fix" thing but worth doing anyway, i'll vote it up so you get at least 2 votes! It looks like "Same Database" references aren't resolved properly and it isn't found until deploy time - seems pretty serious!

Comment: I feared it was so, but I wanted to check with the community first. I'll create a connect item asap. Thanks!

Comment: It seems they've taken it into account: https://twitter.com/sqldatatools/status/691658960948953088